# Ionic 5 Get Request to Slim API

Tags: php, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, slim

I would like to make a get request from my Ionic app to an API build with the Slim Framework.

This is the code of the API:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Tuupola\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$jwt_secret = '**************';

$app = new Slim\App;

$app->add(new Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "attribute" => "jwt",
    "secret" => $jwt_secret,  "error" => function ($response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
            ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            ->getBody()->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));

$app->get('/api/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) 
{
    $decoded = $request->getAttribute("jwt");
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("status"=> "200", "message" => "HELLO ".$decoded['uid'] ." - " . $decoded['cus'])));

    return $response;
});

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("status"=> "200", "message" => "Welcome to the API")));

    return $response;
});

$app->run();

?>
```

When I'm testing with postman the API works fine. But when I'm trying to call it with the HTTPClient in Ionic, it doesn't work. This is my Ionic Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders   } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  {

  }

  sendRequest()
  {
    this.http.get('http://localhost/slim3',).subscribe((data)=>console.log(data));
  }

}
```

The Error message is the following:
:8100/home:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/slim3' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

core.js:6014 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost/slim3", ok: false, …}

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must enable CORS([What is CORS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)) in Slim Framework. Check http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/enable-cors.html

Add this before `$app->run();` (replacing `http://mysite` by your url, including port)

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});

$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mysite')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
            ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem. Same error message like before :/

Comment: Well, I think it is more an ionic problem than a slim problem.
As I said, when testing the slim api with postman, ecerything works fine.

Comment: No, it's not an Ionic problem. Postman doesn't care about [Same-Origin  Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) since it's not a browser. Same will occur with Curl, Insomnia, wget, etc. But browsers care. Unless your API respond correctly to the OPTIONS request made by any browser (including ionic web view), it won't work.

Comment: Okay. I've googled a lot, but I can't find a solution that works